# Looping through all files with specific extension and execute something on them

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

This is my first hours with Linux shell script and it seems really powerful but i am still a little confused.

I want to loop through all the files with a specific extension in a directory **recursively** (all subdirectories, subsubdirectories and ...) and by running an executable on them produce a new file with same name but different extension on exact location of the original file.

Following is the pseudo code for it:

```
files = list of all files (full path not just names) with extension .ext recursively

for file in files
    executable -option1 -option2 fullpath/file.ext1 > fullpath/file.ext2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  find . -name '*.ext1' -type f -exec sh -c \
    'executable -option1 -option2 ${0} > ${0%.ext1}.ext2' {} \;
```

`find` is a standard tool for recursively walking a file tree.  The first argument (in this case '.', meaning the current working directory) specifies the base of the tree at which to begin the descent.  The `-name` argument limits the scope of the search to files that match the given filename.  The `-type f` further limits the search to regular files (as opposed to directories or other entities).  The `-exec` option instructs find to execute the specified command on every file it finds that matched the previous specifications (regular files whose name ends in ".ext1")  We use `sh` to execute the command rather than directly calling the executable for 2 reasons: it is easy to manipulate the filename, and because it is not strictly portable to even try to manipulate the filename with `find`: it must be given exactly as `{}`.

The `${0%.ext1}` is shell syntax that takes the filename (the value of `$0` is the filename, since we pass it as the first argument to `sh` via `{}` in find) and strips off the trailing ".ext1".  We append ".ext2" to that resulting string to get the desired output file.

Answer (score 5):

In `bash` 4 or later, you can take advantage of the `globstar` option, which is set by default.

```sh
for file in **/*.ext1; do
    executable -option1 -option2 "$file" > "${file%.ext1}".ext2
done
```